# LibreSwan IKEv1 XAUTH VPN server -- so close and yet so far

Tags: vpn, libreswan, ikev1

Here's an ASCII-art diagram of my situation

```
      192.168.10.0/24
             |
  +---+  .7  |
  | A |------+                       _____
  +---+      |                      (     )
             | .254 +---+ Ext IP   (       )
             +----Ri| R |Re-------(  cloud  )
             |      +---+          (       )\      iPhone
             |        \             (_____)  \      +---+
                       \                      ------|   |
                        \                           | B |
                         \           192.168.11.80  |   |
                          +------VPN-Tunnel---------|   |
                             IKEv1 XAUTH with PSK   +---+

Legend:
   A  - Windows 7
   R  - CentOS 6.9 acting as a router and iptables firewall,
        with LibreSwan installed
   Ri - Internal interface of R
   Re - External interface of R
   B  - An iPhone SE with iOS 10 configured to use what Apple
        calls "IPSEC" (Cisco) VPN
```

System R has been a working router/iptables firewall in bridge mode for years.

I need to be able to use MS's Remote Desktop client for iOS to log into system A from iOS device B, and decided to set up a VPN server on R.

You may well ask *"Why not just use an SSH client with port forwarding instead"*?  You would have a really good point, and this is what I used to do, but somewhere around iOS 6 Apple stopped allowing background apps to keep network connections open, making a background SSH tunnel impossible.  No current SSH client that claims to support port forwarding can keep a connection open in the background longer than about 90 seconds, so accomplishing my goal requires a VPN.

I set things up using the instructions from [LibreSwan](https://libreswan.org/wiki/VPN_server_for_remote_clients_using_IKEv1_XAUTH_with_PSK)

## Problem Summary

The VPN connection comes up fine but routing from B to A seems to be broken while everything else, including routing from A to B, seems to work.

***Ping Matrix***

```
            To
           A  Ri  Re  B
        A  -  y   y   y
  From  R  y  -   -   y
        B  N  y   y   -
```

In other words, everybody can ping everybody else EXCEPT B cannot ping
anybody inside the 192.168.10.0/24 network, while still being able to
ping R's internal network address.

***Here is `ipsec.conf`***:

```
config setup
        protostack=netkey

        logfile=/var/log/pluto.log

        interfaces="%defaultroute"
        dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
        nat_traversal=yes
        virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12,%v4:25.0.0.0/8,%v4:100.64.0.0/10,%v6:fd00::/8,%v6:fe80::/10,%v4:!192.168.10.0/24
        keep_alive=60

conn xauth-psk
    authby=secret
    pfs=no
    auto=add
    rekey=no
    left=%defaultroute
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    rightaddresspool=192.168.11.80-192.168.11.90
    right=%any
    cisco-unity=yes
    modecfgdns1=192.168.10.254
    leftxauthserver=yes
    rightxauthclient=yes
    leftmodecfgserver=yes
    rightmodecfgclient=yes
    modecfgpull=yes
    xauthby=file
    ike-frag=yes
    ikev2=never
```

***Output of `ipsec verify`:***

```
Verifying installed system and configuration files

Version check and ipsec on-path                         [OK]
Libreswan 3.15 (netkey) on 2.6.32-696.10.1.el6.x86_64
Checking for IPsec support in kernel                    [OK]
 NETKEY: Testing XFRM related proc values
         ICMP default/send_redirects                    [OK]
         ICMP default/accept_redirects                  [OK]
         XFRM larval drop                               [OK]
Pluto ipsec.conf syntax                                 [OK]
Hardware random device                                  [N/A]
Two or more interfaces found, checking IP forwarding    [OK]
Checking rp_filter                                      [OK]
Checking that pluto is running                          [OK]
 Pluto listening for IKE on udp 500                     [OK]
 Pluto listening for IKE/NAT-T on udp 4500              [OK]
 Pluto ipsec.secret syntax                              [OK]
Checking 'ip' command                                   [OK]
Checking 'iptables' command                             [OK]
Checking 'prelink' command does not interfere with FIPSChecking for obsolete ipsec.conf options                 [OK]
Opportunistic Encryption                                [DISABLED]
```

***Output of `ipsec look`:***

```
janus.localdomain Thu Sep  7 20:01:38 PDT 2017
XFRM state:
src xxx.xxx.45.71 dst xxx.xxx.94.61
        proto esp spi 0xde18dd2e reqid 16397 mode tunnel
        replay-window 32 flag 20
        auth hmac(sha1) 0x23faf136fcde2c1b8c31f4cc9fea0003fa2985d2
        enc cbc(aes) 0x04c42120ad0357f2406c5a9fdfe3f5ad8fcc45c3ed3aa69aeb1f010f996e3a10
        encap type espinudp sport 42703 dport 4500 addr 0.0.0.0
src xxx.xxx.94.61 dst xxx.xxx.45.71
        proto esp spi 0x0aa354d9 reqid 16397 mode tunnel
        replay-window 32 flag 20
        auth hmac(sha1) 0x3ecfa164b8455dfca08b985c8e1b326adba2fa2a
        enc cbc(aes) 0xb81e5bfa39b63e493fcce3b2104ee5f2dd2f81fe8a45ec7665dd182493e525f9
        encap type espinudp sport 4500 dport 42703 addr 0.0.0.0
XFRM policy:
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 192.168.11.80/32
        dir out priority 3104 ptype main
        tmpl src xxx.xxx.94.61 dst xxx.xxx.45.71
                proto esp reqid 16397 mode tunnel
src 192.168.11.80/32 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir fwd priority 3104 ptype main
        tmpl src xxx.xxx.45.71 dst xxx.xxx.94.61
                proto esp reqid 16397 mode tunnel
src 192.168.11.80/32 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir in priority 3104 ptype main
        tmpl src xxx.xxx.45.71 dst xxx.xxx.94.61
                proto esp reqid 16397 mode tunnel
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 135
        dir fwd priority 1 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 135
        dir in priority 1 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 136
        dir out priority 1 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 136
        dir fwd priority 1 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 136
        dir in priority 1 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0 proto ipv6-icmp type 135
        dir out priority 1 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        dir 4 priority 0 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        dir 3 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 4 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 3 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 4 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 3 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 4 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 3 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 4 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 3 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 4 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 3 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 4 priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        dir 3 priority 0 ptype main
XFRM done
IPSEC mangle TABLES
NEW_IPSEC_CONN mangle TABLES
ROUTING TABLES
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.254
xxx.xxx.45.0/21 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src xxx.xxx.94.61
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1003
default via xxx.xxx.45.1 dev eth1
unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 mtu 65536
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 mtu 65536
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 mtu 65536
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 mtu 65536
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 mtu 65536
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 mtu 65536
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 mtu 65536
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 mtu 65536
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 mtu 65536
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500
fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500
NSS_CERTIFICATES

Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI
```

***`pluto.log` entries for a connection***

```
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: received Vendor ID payload [RFC 3947]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: ignoring Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: ignoring Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-08]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: ignoring Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-07]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: ignoring Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-06]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: ignoring Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-05]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: ignoring Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-04]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: ignoring Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-03]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: ignoring Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: ignoring Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02_n]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: received Vendor ID payload [XAUTH]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: received Vendor ID payload [Cisco-Unity]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: received Vendor ID payload [FRAGMENTATION 80000000]
Sep  7 20:14:39: packet from xxx.xxx.45.71:18317: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: enabling possible NAT-traversal with method RFC 3947 (NAT-Traversal)
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: responding to Main Mode from unknown peer xxx.xxx.45.71
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: transition from state STATE_MAIN_R0 to state STATE_MAIN_R1
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: STATE_MAIN_R1: sent MR1, expecting MI2
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: NAT-Traversal: Result using RFC 3947 (NAT-Traversal) sender port 18317: peer be
hind NAT
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: transition from state STATE_MAIN_R1 to state STATE_MAIN_R2
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: STATE_MAIN_R2: sent MR2, expecting MI3
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: ignoring informational payload IPSEC_INITIAL_CONTACT, msgid=00000000, length=28
Sep  7 20:14:39: | ISAKMP Notification Payload
Sep  7 20:14:39: |   00 00 00 1c  00 00 00 01  01 10 60 02
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Main mode peer ID is ID_IPV4_ADDR: '10.148.35.161'
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: switched from "xauth-psk"[7] xxx.xxx.45.71 to "xauth-psk"
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: deleting connection "xauth-psk" instance with peer xxx.xxx.45.71 {isakmp=#0/ip
sec=#0}
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: transition from state STATE_MAIN_R2 to state STATE_MAIN_R3
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: new NAT mapping for #5, was xxx.xxx.45.71:18317, now xxx.xxx.45.71:42703
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: STATE_MAIN_R3: sent MR3, ISAKMP SA established {auth=PRESHARED_KEY cipher=aes_2
56 integ=OAKLEY_SHA2_256 group=MODP2048}
Sep  7 20:14:39: | event EVENT_v1_SEND_XAUTH #5 STATE_MAIN_R3
Sep  7 20:14:39: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: XAUTH: Sending Username/Password request (XAUTH_R0)
Sep  7 20:14:54: XAUTH: User jhg: Attempting to login
Sep  7 20:14:54: XAUTH: passwd file authentication being called to authenticate user jhg
Sep  7 20:14:54: XAUTH: password file (/etc/ipsec.d/passwd) open.
Sep  7 20:14:54: XAUTH: checking user(jhg:xauth-psk)
Sep  7 20:14:54: XAUTH: User jhg: Authentication Successful
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: XAUTH: xauth_inR1(STF_OK)
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: transition from state STATE_XAUTH_R1 to state STATE_MAIN_R3
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: STATE_MAIN_R3: sent MR3, ISAKMP SA established
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute INTERNAL_ADDRESS_EXPIRY received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute APPLICATION_VERSION received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute MODECFG_BANNER received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute MODECFG_DOMAIN received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute CISCO_SPLIT_DNS received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute CISCO_SPLIT_INC received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute CISCO_SPLIT_EXCLUDE received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute CISCO_DO_PFS received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute CISCO_SAVE_PW received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute CISCO_FW_TYPE received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute CISCO_BACKUP_SERVER received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: Unsupported modecfg long attribute CISCO_UNKNOWN_SEEN_ON_IPHONE received.
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: modecfg_inR0(STF_OK)
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: transition from state STATE_MODE_CFG_R0 to state STATE_MODE_CFG_R1
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: STATE_MODE_CFG_R1: ModeCfg Set sent, expecting Ack
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #5: the peer proposed: 0.0.0.0/0:0/0 -> 192.168.11.80/32:0/0
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #6: responding to Quick Mode proposal {msgid:9b886838}
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #6:     us: 0.0.0.0/0===xxx.xxx.94.61[MS+XS+S=C]
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #6:   them: xxx.xxx.45.71[10.148.35.161,+MC+XC+S=C]===192.168.11.80/32
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #6: transition from state STATE_QUICK_R0 to state STATE_QUICK_R1
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #6: STATE_QUICK_R1: sent QR1, inbound IPsec SA installed, expecting QI2 tunnel mode
 {ESP/NAT=>0x0e7958fe <0xbbd3b5cf xfrm=AES_256-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=xxx.xxx.45.71:42703 DPD=passive XAUTHuser=jhg}
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #6: transition from state STATE_QUICK_R1 to state STATE_QUICK_R2
Sep  7 20:14:55: "xauth-psk"[8] xxx.xxx.45.71 #6: STATE_QUICK_R2: IPsec SA established tunnel mode {ESP/NAT=>0x0e7958fe <0xbbd3b5
cf xfrm=AES_256-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=xxx.xxx.45.71:42703 DPD=passive XAUTHuser=jhg}
```

To re-summarize: The VPN connects and authenticates OK, no errors or anything fishy in `pluto.log` or `/var/log/secure`, but client B cannot get its packets routed to the A subnet, even though A hosts CAN ping B.

One thing I did try was changing the `interfaces` line in `ipsec.conf' to

```
    interfaces="%defaultroute ipsec0=eth0"
```

but this had no effect, and did not create an interface called `ipsec0`.

## Question

What do I need to change in my config to get routing to happen correctly, so that B can communicate with hosts on the internal subnet?

## Side Note/Additional Information

I notice that routing of packets to and from the remote VPN client does not seem to involve the usual routing mechanisms.  There are no `ipsecn` adapters shown by the `ip` command, so I guess I don't understand yet how ipsec and routing interact.

The router/firewall R has masquerading enabled for outgoing traffic:

***`iptables-restore` NAT table section (`eth1` is external adapter)***

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

***`iptables-restore` input filter:***

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

-A INPUT   -i lo   -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT   -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT   -i eth1 -j INPUT_FILTER

:INPUT_FILTER - [0:0]
-A INPUT_FILTER -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_FILTER -p udp --dport  500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_FILTER -p udp --dport 1701 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_FILTER -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_FILTER -p udp -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -m udp --dport 1701 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_FILTER -p 50 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_FILTER -p 51 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT_FILTER -j DROP
```

But since there are no VPN adapters I'm not sure what I'd change here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem demonstrates the critical importance of having a correct mental model of what's going on.

Simply put, the ipsec tunnel was working just fine, but I needed to tweak some firewall rules both on the router (R above) and the Windows machine (A above).

I had assumed/guessed that ipsec was providing some kind of virtual network interface to represent the tunnel, but for some reason I could not see it, and didn't know where to find it.  I finally found the command

```
ipsec_tncfg (5) - lists IPSEC virtual interfaces attached to real interfaces
```

but running this gave

```
[jhg@janus ~]$ sudo ipsec tncfg
/usr/libexec/ipsec/tncfg: NETKEY does not support virtual interfaces.
```

After some methodical analysis of packet flow I had the epiphany:

> ipsec completely hides itself, and all tunneled traffic looks like it is coming in un-tunneled from the external world, but with RFC-1918 private source addresses.

Normally you would never see incoming traffic with an RFC-1918 source address, and my iptables FORWARD chain was configured to silently drop everything that wasn't `--state RELATED,ESTABLISHED`.

So, the simple answer is to add a rule in the FORWARD chain that allows packets from the addresspool range to be forwarded.  In iptables-restore format:

```
# THIS IS A TEMPORARY HACK TO DEMONSTRATE THAT IT FIXES THE ISSUE
# IN A PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT THIS WOULD BE A SECURITY RISK
-A FORWARD_FILTER -i eth1 -s 192.168.11.64/26 -o eth0 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

<sub>I understand that this is a relatively minor (but non-zero) security risk as it now allows someone to place a rogue host on the subnet at my ISP, configured in the `192.168.11.64/26` range and get past my firewall.  I also know there are options in iptables to restrict this hole to ipsec only (`--m policy --pol ipsec ...`) but I have to read the man page and do some research. If I can't get that to work it's a separate question.  When I get it working I'll come back and update this answer.</sub>

That didn't quite work, the packets now made it as far as host A but were not being responded to.  But that was easily explained because Windows Firewall didn't recognize the addresspool subnet, so adding a firewall rule there finally made everything work as expected.

Next up is to move the addresspool to overlay part of the internal LAN subnet so I can dispense with the Windows Firewall rule.  But that's for another day.